# SQL Update query for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm in need of some help:

I'm using the following statement to update a table.

```
 UPDATE [Raw Data]

 SET Line_Currency='GBP', Currency_Amount

 WHERE Line_Currency='DEM' and Base_Amount
```

Basically I need to change currency from `DEM` to `GBP` (For 2 rows). and need to replace the Currency Amount column figures with the Base amount column figures.

Would appreciate some assistance! Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what error are you getting? UPDATE statements can very well update more than one column in any RDBMS. It is not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
    UPDATE [Raw Data]

SET Line_Currency='GBP', Currency_Amount = Base_Amount

WHERE Line_Currency='DEM'
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! As you can see I just started using SQL :D

Comment: @user3664003 -- then you should start with some tutorials. This is really basic UPDATE syntax